# Node js, express and handlebars - where to apply logic to data before rendering

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am new to node js, express and the handlebar template engine.

I have managed to get data from a json feed and it is rendering correctly in the view. I am doing this by getting the data in the app, then passing the data into and from the router to the view.

However, I need to manipulate and add some logic to some of the json data and the render it.

The feed i have is of an article, it has a publish date value which is in a particular format and i need to format it accordingly and then render it.

My question is, where do i apply the logic for data manipulation so when i render it via the handlebars template, it renders the required format.

The boiler plate folder structure i have setup is;

/server
...
/src
...
/views
...

In the view, i have the following in the home.hndlebars file.

```
<div class="publish">{{{ article.post.date }}}</div>
```

I need to format that value.

Thanks

Comment: Thats usually done in something called controller, that is between the router and the view

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how do i do this?

Comment: Just type express mvc in google, there are a lot of tuto... exemple : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-complete-mvc-website-with-expressjs--net-34168

Answer (score 1):

you can make a helper in handlebars it's very helpful in many cases. for yours I would do something like this:

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const moment = require('moment')
var hbs = exphbs.create({
          defaultLayout: 'main.handlebars',
          // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
          helpers: {
             moment: function(date) {
                    return moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
                }

             }
        })
```

and then in the html you use the helpers like this:

```
<div class="publish">{{#moment article.post.date}}{{/moment}}</div>
```